# Should I use ConcurrentHashMap or Hashmap or SynchronizedMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have created a hashmap outside my mutithreading code. There are going to be no changes in this hasmap later.

After this, I am starting two threads which will both be reading from this hashmap(yes, only read operations). If thread1 is reading from my hashmap object , can thread 2 also read at the same time? Or do I need a Concurrenthashmap or any other version of Map?

Comment: No, you don't need `ConcurrentHashMap`, what you should really pass to your consumers is either a `ImmutableMap` or a `UnmodifiableMap`

Comment: As you are going to do only read operations , there is no need for a synchronized version of map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If thread1 is reading from my hashmap object, can thread 2 also read
>   at the same time?

If you are sure that there are no write operations then you need not use Synchronization options at all, Go for a normal version of Map.

You can also use [Immutable Map](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)

> A Map whose contents will never change, with many other important
>   properties detailed at ImmutableCollection

Comment: Hi, I have declared my map as final so that I can use it in my anonymous inner class of Callable.This should be okay, right?  or do u think it is better to use ImmutableCollection?

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need concurrent Hash maps..but only since you don not do any modifications. You can read the same without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you required only read operation then no need to use synchronization.If you are not doing any write after creation make it immutable so no body can change it .No need for synchronization.